# Checking if an option in my form is selected won't work

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I'm trying to check if an option is selected in my form (any option) though it's not working.

I'm checking the  not the  specifically; this is my code:

```js
if (document.getElementById('fillingtype') = selected;) {
  alert('yes');
} else {
  alert('no');
}
```

```html
<select id="fillingtype" name="filling">
  <option id="tuna" value="tunamayo">Tuna Mayo</option>
  <option value="smokeychicken">Smokey Chicken + Crisp Lettuce</option>
  <option value="pizza">Meat Feast Pizza filling</option>
  <option value="hamcheese">Ham + Cheese</option>
</select>
```

I can't seem to get it to work, any suggestions on different solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Syntax error: `if (document.getElementById('fillingtype').selected)` A single = does assignment, not comparison, so basically you're saying 'set the dom element i get from the document to the variabel selected' instead of 'if the element I got from the DOm is selecten, then...'

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is always a selected value (by default it will be Tuna Mayo), You can add a listener to when a user selects a new value like that:

```js
document.getElementById('fillingtype').addEventListener('change',function(){ 
  console.log(this.value) 
});
```

```html
<select id="fillingtype" name="filling">
  <option id="tuna" value="tunamayo">Tuna Mayo</option>
  <option value="smokeychicken">Smokey Chicken + Crisp Lettuce</option>
  <option value="pizza">Meat Feast Pizza filling</option>
  <option value="hamcheese">Ham + Cheese</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could add a non-option by default with an empty value.

```
<option selected value="">Please Select</option>
```

And if the value is empty means that the user didn't select any option:

```
if(document.getElementById('fillingtype').value)
```

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mpad/8es6eunm/4/

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="fillingtype" name="filling">
  <option value="tunamayo">Tuna Mayo</option>
  <option value="smokeychicken">Smokey Chicken + Crisp Lettuce</option>
  <option value="pizza">Meat Feast Pizza filling</option>
  <option value="hamcheese">Ham + Cheese</option>
</select>
   </form>

<script>
$( "#fillingtype" ).change(function() {
alert($( "#fillingtype option:selected" ).text());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/tikifi/1/edit?html,js,console,output